# Lock the camera's Y position in BGE?

Tags: game-engine

I am making a 2D platformer. I parented the camera to the player so that the camera follows the player.
However, whenever the player jumps, the camera also jumps.

How can I get the camera to not jump with the player?
Can I lock camera's Y position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of parenting the Camera to the Player, use this code to copy the location of the Player to the location of the Camera:

```
import bge
import GameLogic as g
cont = g.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
scene = g.getCurrentScene()

player = scene.objects["Player"]
camera = scene.objects["Camera"]

loc = player.position
x = loc[0]
y = loc[1]
z = loc[2]

own.worldPosition = [x, y, z]
```

Since you don't want it to move on every axis along with the Camera, i would simply fill in each axis in the `own.worldPosition = [x, y, z]` line that you dont want to be changed with the camera's actual location. For example my line reads `own.worldPosition = [x, -30, 5.8]`. This keeps the Camera locked on the y and z axes while copying the x location of the Player. Hope this helped. :)

Comment: import bge
import GameLogic as g
cont = g.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
scene = g.getCurrentScene()

player = scene.objects["Player"]
camera = scene.objects["Camera"]

loc = player.position
x = loc[0]
y = loc[1]
z = loc[2]

own.worldPosition = [x, y, z]       please explane this code my player name is plr. i tried it but  got an error